# Why can't I catch the response error returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I maked a service for change password, but when something is wrong, backend return this object with information of error.

```
    {
        "name": "BadRequest",
        "message": "The password is wrong!",
        "code": 400,
        "className": "bad-request",
        "errors": {}
    }
```

But my statement catch only get ```` Error: Request failed with status code 400``` when should it be the message with the tratament maked in the backend and not a generic message like this.

```
await api.post ('api / v1 / change-password /', data


    ) .then (response => {
         console.log ('response', response)
         Toast.show ({
            

text: 'Information updated successfully!',
            duration: 5000,
            style: styleProperties.successToast,
            textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
            position: 'top',
            buttonText: 'OK',
            buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
            });
        }). catch (error => {

            console.log ('error', error);
            Toast.show ({
                text: 'error.message,
                duration: 5000,
                style: styleProperties.dangerToast,
                textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
                position: 'top',
                buttonText: 'OK',
                buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
            });

        }). finally (function () {
            instance.ShowHideActivityIndicator ();
        });
```

How I make to get the returned variable message with the cause of the error? I want show to user the cause of error with the tratament maked in the backend e not a generic message like this `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

Thank you !!

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` with method-chaining. That's why your `catch` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `async`/`await` with method-chaining. That's why your `catch` isn't working.

As you can use `await`, use it properly:

```
try {
    const resp = await api.post( 'api / v1 / change-password /', data );
    console.log( 'response', resp );

    const successToastOpts = {
        text: 'Information updated successfully!',
        duration: 5000,
        style: styleProperties.successToast,
        textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
        position: 'top',
        buttonText: 'OK',
        buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
    };

    Toast.show( successToastOpts );
}
catch( err ) {
    
    debugger;
    console.error( err );
    
    const errorToastOpts = {
        text: ( 'message' in err ) ? err.message : JSON.stringify( err ),
        duration: 5000,
        style: styleProperties.dangerToast,
        textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
        position: 'top',
        buttonText: 'OK',
        buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
    };

    Toast.show( errorToastOpts );
} 
finally {
    instance.ShowHideActivityIndicator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `async/await` you have to use `try` `catch` to catch the `error`
but in your code since you are using `.then` just remove `await` from your code

```js
api.post ('api / v1 / change-password /', data


    ) .then (response => {
         console.log ('response', response)
         Toast.show ({
            

text: 'Information updated successfully!',
            duration: 5000,
            style: styleProperties.successToast,
            textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
            position: 'top',
            buttonText: 'OK',
            buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
            });
        }). catch (error => {

            console.log ('error', error);
            Toast.show ({
                text: 'error.message,
                duration: 5000,
                style: styleProperties.dangerToast,
                textStyle: styleProperties.textToast,
                position: 'top',
                buttonText: 'OK',
                buttonTextStyle: styleProperties.successButtonTextToast,
            });

        }). finally (function () {
            instance.ShowHideActivityIndicator ();
        });
```